# curl --connect-timeout and --max-time does not work as expected

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, curl, c-ares

The following command will `wait > 60 seconds` on `Ubuntu 22.04`:

```
curl --verbose --retry-max-time 0 --retry 0 --connect-timeout "30" --max-time "60" "https://www.google.com/"
```

Here is the testing result:

```
root@test:~# echo $(date)
Tue Dec 6 07:26:04 PM CST 2022

root@test:~# curl --verbose --retry-max-time 0 --retry 0 --connect-timeout "30" --max-time "60" "https://www.google.com/"

* Resolving timed out after 30000 milliseconds
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Resolving timed out after 30000 milliseconds

root@test:~# echo $(date)
Tue Dec 6 07:28:26 PM CST 2022
```

Here is the version:

```
root@test:~# curl --version
curl 7.81.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.81.0 OpenSSL/3.0.2 zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.4.8 libidn2/2.3.2 libpsl/0.21.0 (+libidn2/2.3.2) libssh/0.9.6/openssl/zlib nghttp2/1.43.0 librtmp/2.3 OpenLDAP/2.5.12
Release-Date: 2022-01-05
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli GSS-API HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SPNEGO SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets zstd
```

**The expected behavior:**

> The whole timeout should not exceed the 60 seconds or 30 seconds as it
> already timeout in Resolving DNS.

What's the problem and how to fix the timeout with curl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that DNS is not resolving properly and causing cURL to take longer. The issue you describe, looking at your cURL version seems to be similar to what is below:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/571246/curl-max-time-and-connect-timeout-not-working-at-all

Instead of cracking your head with rebuilding cURL and configuring it with c-ares, it might be worth a try to test whether a server is reachable first and then initiate cURL:

`ping -c 1 google.com &>/dev/null && cURL ...whatever`

By default ping will extend timeout by max 4 seconds, which you can finetune using `-W` option